# Elixir - Starting a Java JInterface OTP node under supervision

Tags: java, erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, jinterface

I have an elixir umbrella project where one of the apps sends requests to a Java app that I have exposed as something similar to an OTP process using JInterface.

It works perfectly because the JInterface library that ships with Erlang makes it easy.

My problem is that I need to be able to stop and start my JInterface process in my umbrella app and I can't find any documentation that shows how to do it. I currently have to execute the jar manually.

Please can somebody explain / point me towards documentation showing how I can execute my jar from within elixir under supervision?

I have tried for so long to find out how to do this but I can only find docs on how to use JInterface and how to interface with it but not how to start it programatically under supervision.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A long time ago I had to do just that, and the result was [lucene_server](https://github.com/inaka/lucene_server).
You can find code for node monitoring [here](https://github.com/inaka/lucene_server/blob/3eff0f5d2ddf0119cf5244a35cd3a3c40aef5a6d/src/lucene.erl#L228-L242). Something along the lines of…

```
true = link(process()),
true = erlang:monitor_node(State#state.java_node, true),
```

Another thing that you might find useful (from the Java side) is to use [jinerface_stdlib](https://github.com/inaka/jinterface_stdlib)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this.